# Metodo que en visual basic no toma parametros como se hace en C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, hilos

Estoy haciendo la siguiente conversión de código de vb .net a c#

```
Thread hilo = new Thread(AddressOf ConcatenarArchivosHilos);
            hilos.Add(hilo);
```

donde ConcatenarArchivosHilos tiene un parámetro de un array de integer

```
Private Sub ConcatenarArchivosHilos(ByVal indices() As Integer)
   'el resto del codigo
End Sub
```

al hacer la conversión a c# lo convierte (http://converter.telerik.com/)

```
Thread hilo = new Thread(ConcatenarArchivosHilos);

private void ConcatenarArchivosHilos(int[] indices)
 {
       //El resto de codigo
 }
```

en c# lo normal seria que ConcatenarArchivosHilos le indicara un array de indices así

```
 Thread hilo = Tread(concatenarArchivosHilos(Arrayindices))
```

pero como explique viene de código VB.net donde esa porción de código **NO** tiene el parámetro del método ConcatenarArchivosHilos, alguien puede explicar porque?

**Actualización**

**hilos[numeroLinea].Start(indicesAProcesar);** en esta tomando los parámetros para iniciar hilos.

El error que sale en tiempo de diseño es  **cannot convert from 'method group' to 'ThreadStart'**

Comment: en vb.net como asignas el array de parametros "indices" ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini solo tengo esta linea de código: **Thread hilo = new Thread(AddressOf ConcatenarArchivosHilos);**

Comment: en vb.net no usas el Start() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias usar algo como ser

```
Thread hilo = Tread(concatenarArchivosHilos);
hilo.Start(Arrayindices);
```

al definir el `Start()` es donde pasas los parametros, analiza la documentacion

[Thread.Start Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.start?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Thread_Start_System_Object_)

veras ejemplo de como el metodo Start() del thread permie pasar los parametros

Comment: lo inicializo en esta linea en vb **hilos(numeroLinea).Start(indicesAProcesar);** en c# lo tengo **hilos[numeroLinea].Start(indicesAProcesar);** que esta en un ciclo for

Comment: en ese Start() es que debes pasar el parametro, entiendo que indicesAProcesar es ese valor

Comment: en teoría todo esta bien el parámetro es correcto indicesAprocesar, pero sigue sacando el error  **cannot convert from 'method group' to 'ThreadStart'**

Comment: que pasa si quitas la lista "hilos" de en medio y lanzas solo un thread, para ver si lo hace correctamente